# How to get notified when glTexImage2D finished upload?

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es, textures

I want to render after a texture is uploaded to OpenGL, but I cannot get notified about the completition.

I do want to avoid using animation, or any kind of repetitive rendering.

Is glTexImage2D asynchronous at all? As far as I know, almost every OpenGL call is async.

---

It would be great anyway, if I could be informed about a glDrawArrays completition as well.

Comment: Please don't edit your question away into oblivion. As it stands you're not asking a question now and just throwing a random sentence at us. Don't delete it either, just accept a correct answer, if any.

Comment: "nowhow" is a suitable answer? What does that even mean? If you need to get notified after synchronous calls has completed, just write this yourself using a callback. No need for built in openGL methods for this.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo No, if you need to get notified after synchronous calls, **do nothing and just wait for the call to return**, it's synchronous.

Comment: @ChristianRau - Yes, even better of course. I was just picturing him needing to write a delegate a similar if the code is entangled in a larger function. But you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is, just continue after the call to `glTexImage2D` returns. From your point of view it is a synchronous call in the sense that everything is properly set up after it returns. You can make texture uploads asynchronous by using PBOs as intermediate storage, but even then everything is managed by the driver for you and all you need to know is that when `glTexImage2D` returns you can assume the texture data to be properly uploaded and start rendering. If the texture data is not yet uploaded internally your things won't get rendered anyway and will wait for the texture to be set up.

You are correct that most OpenGL calls can be seen as asynchronous in the sense that they only schedule commands to be sent to the graphics card and the driver decides when to finally send them to the hardware and the hardware is free to decide when to process them, not to speak of the fact that nobody knows when they're actually finished. But you know what, you usually just don't care. If anything needs to block in order to wait for some previous operation to complete (like an asynchronous texture upload), then it will be managed for you automagically and once an OpenGL function returned you can be sure it has done its work from your point of view.

disclaimer: There are indeed situations when you really need to know when an actual operation has finally finished its work on the device. Though your scenario isn't one of those. One of the few situations when you might really want to synchronize operations is, when you are timing something for debugging or profiling reasons. And since OpenGL ES probably lacks [ARB_timer_query](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/timer_query.txt), issuing a `glFinish` (like suggested in *BlueVoodoo*'s answer) might be an option in this case.

**EDIT:** In the same way you don't get notified when your things drawn with `glDrawArrays` are finally rendered to screen, but you just don't care about it.

Comment: What if I'm uploading the texture data in one thread (in one context) and I need to use it in another thread (another, but shared, context)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant it's an asynchronous call? Otherwise, why do you need to get notified? If you need it to be synchronous, have a look at [glFinish()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFinish.xml). I don't know of any notifications for openGL methods.