# How to calculate the texture loading time in opengl es?

Tags: opengl-es, textures

For calculating the Texture Loading Time, is it enough to measure the execution time of glTexImage2D()?

Is there any other methods to calculate the texture loading time in opengl?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032381/how-to-get-notified-when-glteximage2d-finished-upload)

Answer (score 2):

glTexImage2D is a synchronous (mostly... it depends on the driver and gpu, but from your perspective it is) function, meaning that you can assume that everything is set up and ready to go when it returns. Therefore, you should only have to measure the execution time of glTexImage2D to figure out the loading time.